# ajax control toolkit's tab container(shifting tab header to right side)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a TabContainer from Ajax Control Toolkit (asp.net) and it looks like this

[image]

I have tried it a lot and searched a lot but there seems to be no answer present.

I want the tab header [Canada][US][Europe] to appear on the right side

Is it possible, how can I accomplish this?

I really want to use the toolkit's tab container

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add/override this css class property

```
        .ajax__tab_header
        {
        margin-left:310px !important;
        }
```